# Getting (NoMethodError) as if object has not been created

Tags: ruby

I'm having difficulty running the following. I get the following error 
"': undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)"
at the

```
puts shopper[i].name
```

line

As if sometimes the object hasn't been created by the time it gets to that line

```
(0 .. 9).each do |i|
  shopper[i] = Shopper.new("Shopper Number-#{i}")
  (0 .. 19).each do |j|
    r = rand(0 .. (k-1))
    if shopper[i].unsuccessful_shopping_trip == true
      puts "#{shopper[i].name} has failed to buy 3 times and has decided to go home"
      i += 1
      break
    else
      if shopper[i].add_product(shop.remove_product_bought_by_shopper(r)) == false
        puts "#{shopper[i].name} has tried to buy #{(shop.products[r]).name} but it is sold out"
        j -= 1
      else
        puts "#{shopper[i].name} has bought #{(shop.products[r]).name}"
      end
    end
  end

  puts shopper[i].name
  puts shopper[i].shopping_list
  total_shopper_net += shopper[i].total_net_value
  total_shopper_gross += shopper[i].how_much_spent
  total_shopper_product_count += shopper[i].total_product_count

end
```

Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are manually incrementing `i` within the `each` iterator.  Any subsequent reference to `shopper[i]` does not yet exist, since shoppers are created only at the top of the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I should have realised the break is only acting on the inner loop